# Interesting Bug: CSS works on Localhost but not live

Tags: css

I've an absurd bug where the span:hover pseudo-class works on my localhost but doesn't work when I upload the stylesheet on my live host. [Here's](http://www.whooshtranscription.com/sheldon-amy-marriage-and-a-gravy-boat/) the live page, and   here's the [stylesheet](http://pastebin.com/j561DJs7). The annoying css is:

```
#transcript {
padding: 10px;
background: #FFF;
font-size: small;
border: 1px solid #9BA6C2;
height: 270px;
overflow: auto;
color: #333;
```

}

```
#transcript.enabled span:hover {
background: #FF3;
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.33);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.33);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.33);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow(color=#CCC, offX=0, offY=1, positive=true);
```

}

I've tested this on latest Mozilla and Chrome and they both don't work. I can't figure out why it works on localhost but not on live. Help!

Comment: That css rule doesn't exist in `style.css` on the live site. Are you sure you're overwriting the correct file, and it's not cached (w3 total cache, supercache etc)?

Comment: Not using a cache plugin. And yes I've overwritten the correct file. Maybe my host is caching the site. Let me check.

Comment: The live style.css is minified, and your source isn't. Minification plugin?

Comment: @christian Yup, minification was the issue. Disabled cloudflare and voila. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the live site.

id="transcript" does not exist.

Comment: It does exist on line 259, but not referenced in the CSS.